# Share View between ListView and ScrollView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-view, android-scrollview

I have the following layout:

[image: layout]

when I click on Btn 1, the Content will be a `ListView`, clicking on Btn 2, will show a `LinearLayout`. My problem is that I want the whole thing to scroll. So if my root is a `ScrollView`, the content displayed with Btn 2 is fine, but as we know, it ain't working with `ListView`.

So instead, my root layout includes 2 layouts:

```
<RelativeLayout id="root">
    <include layout=listViewLayout />
    <include layout=scrollViewLayout />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And the idea is to have a header view:

[image: header]

such that when the root view is created, I inflate the header, set is as header view to the `ListView` (working fine), and add it to the `ScrollView`. But as soon as I add it (technically, it'a added to a `LinearLayout` inside the `ScrollView`), then I get the following crash:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams
```

Technically, I could have two headers doing exactly the same thing (set picture, set listeners to buttons), but for the sake of avoiding duplication, what are the other alternatives?
If I add the header as a row (instead of a using `listView.addHeaderView`) and modify my adapter to handle different layouts, will it solve the problem?

Thanks!

EDIT: to clarify, when I click on Btn 1 or 2, I simply show / hide the layouts. I don't dynamically modify the ViewGroup. It allows me to show either the `ListView` + header or the `ScrollView`. The exception occurs the first time the root is displayed. But if I don't try to add the header view in the `ScrollView`, then it's programmatically working fine.

EDIT 2: sharing 1 header (`View`) among 2 `ListViews` is not working either. From a UI point of view, it looks ok, but the interaction is not (some buttons stop responding to click).
Also, I can't have only 1 `ListView` because the content is pulled from the web, which means I'll have to store / restore everything each time I switch between views.

Comment: You could add some code as well.

Comment: If I understand the exception correctly, you're dynamically removing the top ViewGroup and attempting to set it as the ListView header?

Comment: *what are the other alternatives?* - use a `ListView` as the root and simulate the different layouts with different row types(along with having the `ImageView` declared as the header for the `ListView`(which I assume you want to scroll with the list itself)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the only way to achieve this it to duplicate the header (create 2 instances of the same `View`)...

Answer (score 0):

You should never put a listView inside a scrollView (or the opposite).

You'd better watch the lecture "[**the world of listView**](http://lanyrd.com/2010/io2010/smwm/)" to learn how you should handle such cases.

One way to handle it is to either have a header for the listView, or create a new viewType for each special row you wish to create.

Comment: _You should never put a listView inside a scrollView (or the opposite)_ yes, like noted in my post.

Comment: Then I'm not sure what the problem is. if you just want to switch between views, use ViewSwitcher .